# Export Data from Java to a text file

Tags: java, macos, export

I want to export the character's name and gender to a text file. Also, I need to export on both Mac and PC computers. I've tried various methods, but none has worked for me or I might have placed them incorrectly.

I changed my code with my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Character {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String characterGender;
        String characterName;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Ricardo's character creator!");

        System.out.println("Is your character a boy or a girl?");
        characterGender = scan.nextLine();

        if (characterGender.equals("girl"))  {
             System.out.println("Awesome! Please enter her name: ");
             characterName = scan.nextLine();
        } else {
             System.out.println("Awesome! Please enter his name: ");
             characterName = scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.print("Alright! " + characterName + " has been created!");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Character.txt");
        out.println(characterName);
        out.println(characterGender);
        out.close();

    }
}
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> Character.java:34: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the FileNotFoundException. This can be done either by:

Catching the exception (Preferred method):

```
PrintWriter out;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter("Character.txt");
    out.println(characterName);
    out.println(characterGender);
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("File doesn't exist");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or by throwing the exception:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Note: `import java.io.FileNotFoundException;` must be included in both cases.

Here is some java documentation on [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using File writer Instead of print Writer.
Below is my example code, Hope you do not mind the hard interpretation.

```
String filetowrite = "C:/Users/Desktop/test.txt"; // Point to your location
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filetowrite);
fw.write("Hello, This is the test");
fw.close();
```

Comment: This would still encounter the problem the OP had, which was not handling exceptions. It would simply be an IOException instead of a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are **reading data from Console & writing it to file** it is recommended to **use BufferedReader & BufferedWriter** for it. To handle exception & if you want to add details of exception occurred in Log file using [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/async.html), you can do something like below :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Character.class); 
try {
    String data;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    File file = new File("Character.txt");
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(data);
        bw.write(data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    StringWriter() stack = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
    logger.fatal(stack.toString(), Character.class);
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null && bw != null){
            bw.close();
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        StringWriter() stack = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
        logger.fatal(stack.toString(), Character.class);
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can use `try-with-resources`, available from JDK 1.7 onwards, which will take care of closing resources used. In your case, it's a file.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    String data;
    File file = new File("Character.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(data);
        bw.write(data);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: OP is not reading from file, he is reading from standard input. He wants to write to a file.